# Removing -Zi flag with qmake, for Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio, qt, visual-studio-2012, qmake, vcproj

I have a large Visual Studio 2012 Solution with about 15 Projects inside. I would really like to disable debugging symbol generation for a few of these Projects; the rest should allow debugging. All of this is related to the Debug configuration.

I'm having a terrible time making this happen. The only mention of Zi in my pro files looks like this:

```
# Get rid of debug information
QMAKE_CFLAGS_DEBUG -= -Zi
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_DEBUG -= -Zi
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE_WITH_DEBUGINFO -= -Zi
```

But when I load the Solution file, `Property Pages` -> `C/C++` -> `All Options` -> `Debug Information Format`, the `Program Database (/Zi)` option is still displayed. I also removed any mention of Zi in the mkspecs and qmake.conf (even though the above -= lines should have removed it).

So I opened the qmake source code (every file under qmake/generators/win32), and I see that there doesn't seem to be a way to turn off debug symbols; only the absence of a `-Zi` should prevent it from showing up.

If I set a project to `<inherit from parent or project defaults>` manually, the `Zi` option shows up again. Which leads me to believe it's being inherited... but from where?!

I'm losing my mind. Please help.

---

**EDIT 1:**

Apparently, the inherited properties comes from [the Microsoft.Cpp.* property sheets](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsproject/archive/2009/06/23/inherited-properties-and-property-sheets.aspx). Follow the instructions in that link for finding the property sheets inherited by your project, and you can modify them to get rid of the `-Zi` flag.

It sure would be nice to have a flag that forces `None` for the `Debug Information Format`. Anyone know what that might be?

---

**EDIT 2:**

Third idea: try to change the default location of the inherited property sheets to somewhere I can control.

The Windows environment variable $(UserRootDir) specifies the location of the inherited property sheets. MSBUILD [allegedly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms164311.aspx) allows you to change the value of this variable with the `/property` command line argument. Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to get qmake to accept the argument. Is there any way to set input arguments to the qmake MAKEFILE_GENERATOR builder?

This quest is starting to feel like a wild goose chase. If CMD had sed abilities, I'd just write a script to change the `<DebugInformationFormat>` inside the vcxproj file and be done.

Answer (score 0):

I submitted [QTBUG-32885](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-32885) for that 2 months ago, but it hasn't been fixed yet.

For now you can patch your qmake as described in the ticket.